# ¿Porque la etiqueta l-map se sobre pone a v-navigation-drawer, vuetify?

Tags: vue.js

Buen día,

```
<template>
    <v-card fluid>
        <div class="text-xs-center">
            <v-btn outline small fab color="indigo" @click="abrirmodalBusqueda()">
              <v-icon>search</v-icon>
            </v-btn>
        </div>
        <div id="map">
            <l-map style="height: 500px; width: 100%" :zoom="zoom" :center="center" @update:center="centerUpdate">
                <l-tile-layer :url="url"></l-tile-layer>
                <l-marker :lat-lng="marker" >
                    <l-popup>Estoy en estas coordenadas asadsad {{latitud}}</l-popup>
                </l-marker>

                <l-marker v-for="marker in markers" :lat-lng="marker">
                    <l-popup>Estoy en estas coordenadas asadsad {{marker.lat}}
                        <v-flex xs12 sm4 text-xs-center>
                            <div>
                                <v-btn small color="primary" @click="dialogParqueos = true">Seleccionar</v-btn>
                            </div>
                        </v-flex>
                    </l-popup>
                </l-marker>
            </l-map>
        </div>
    </v-card>
</template>
```

Al utilizar la propiedad de altura en px y no en % ya puedo visualizar el mapa `l-map style="height: 500px"` ya que si utilizo 100% no se ve el mapa.
El problema que al hacer uso de v-navigation-drawer el mapa se monta de la siguiente forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como notaran se sobre pone al panel izquierdo. 
Para el mapa estoy utilizando la librería Vue2Leaflet

De antemano muchas gracias.